# Output the first regex match against STDIN

Tags: regex, bash, perl

In bash, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash 
curl $1 | tac | tac | perl -e '/(\d\d(?=:\d\d))/g; print $1' > $2
```

All I want is to the first match from the output of `curl` and print it to the output file. I run the script with `./scriptname url outputfile.txt` but nothing is printed. My regex is valid on http://regexr.com, so I'm sure it's something I don't know about Perl. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is the output from `curl`?

Comment: The perl script should be `perl -ne 'print if /regex/'`

Comment: The output of curl is quite long. It's the entire html that makes up a large webpage. `perl -ne 'print if /regex/'` didn't have quite the desired output but it did get me much closer to the answer. I may be doing something else wrong as well. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: The regex you have it stupid as it's basically: `\d\d:\d\d`. No need for a look ahead.

Comment: Not exactly. The regex I have is the \d\d portion of \d\d:\d\d For example, if I have "10:00", The regex matches the "10". I don't want the ":00" which is the reason for the look ahead.

Comment: ... And it does no change as you are not using the capturing text to anything. Then change it to `print $1 if /(re)gex/` to print the captured result.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One last thing, though. Making that modification, it seems perl does a global search even if I drop the "g" from the end of my regex. I suppose this means perl -ne is reading the input line by line. Is there a simple way to have perl return only the first result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "$1" | perl -nle'print for /\d\d(?=:\d\d)/g' > "$2"
```

If you change the match to `/script/g`, you can see it working with something like

```
./scriptname http://www.ucsd.edu outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Though @andlrc was extremely helpful, this post puts everything together succinctly for any future passersby

Comment: `if (//g)` makes no sense. Fixed it (and undid other changes for the worse).

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose this means perl -ne is reading the input line by line. Is there a simple way to have perl return only the first result?

Consider using sed:

```
... | sed '/^.*\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\):[[:digit:]]\{2\}.*/{s//\1/;q};d'
```

In Perl, that would be:

```
... | perl -nle 'if (s/^.*(\d\d):\d\d.*/$1/) { print; exit }'
```

And with GNU Grep compiled with `--perl-regexp`:

```
... | grep -m1 -Po '\d\d(?=:\d\d)'
```

Comment: @ikegami I never stated it is, but the result is the same, since I only capture `\d\d`.

Comment: There is nothing to consider since I don't use `/g`

Comment: @ikegami See the quote, OP state they wanting the first result *only*. Sort of like `grep -o | head -1` but with a lookahead.

Comment: Don't you hate it when they change the question in the comments? Still, using `s///` makes no sense here. `perl -nle'if (/(\d\d):\d\d/) { print $1; exit }'` or `perl -nle'if (/\d\d(?=:\d\d)/) { print $&; exit }'` would be much cleaner. [Can't remove downvote]

Comment: I answered in sed, because I find sed to be the least overhead for the question asked as well as being highly portable. The Perl is simply there is explain what the sed is doing; Next time you should properly read before downvoting then ;-)

Comment: I did properly read the question before downvoting. // Perl is actually more portable (AFAIK, `sed` will only work on unix boxes, whereas Perl can be installed on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- You never read from STDIN.
- You don't stop trying to match after the first match.
- You print unconditionally.

If you want all matches (as per your original question):

```
perl -nle'print for /\d\d(?=:\d\d)/g'
```

If you want the first match (as per your comment):

```
perl -nle'if (/\d\d(?=:\d\d)/) { print $&; exit }'

perl -nle'if (/(\d\d):\d\d/) { print $1; exit }'

grep -Pom1 '\d\d(?=:\d\d)'
```

Notes:

- `-n` wraps the code with a loop that reads from STDIN.